# Criar uma subrotina em VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou a tentar criar uma subrotina capaz de ler todo o alfabeto de A até Z e que guarde/apresente as letras lidas em duplicado (AA, BB, CC, ...) em `VB6` mas ainda não deu certo.

A minha tentativa:

```
Do  while alfa <> z
    alfa = alfa + a
    lstalfabeto.additem alfa
Loop
```

Comment: Dá para entender que anda a tentar aprender VB6/VBA e está a ter algumas dificuldades (é normal). Sugeria-lhe que lê-se os seguintes tutoriais (estão em PT) ([Tutorial1](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20373949/Apostila-Excel-VBA-Completa-PORTUGUES-1) e [Tutorial2](http://reocities.com/ResearchTriangle/system/6408/vbasic/fr_vbasic.htm)). Acredito que no fim de os ler vai conseguir expressar melhor as suas dúvidas (ou quiçá não ter dúvidas.)

Comment: O  primeiro tutorial não abriu mas gostei  tem muita coisa que preciso saber defacto,mas gostaria de ter o código que me permite  mover  uma imagem de um lado para o outro não sei se é possível implementar isto no vb6 se sim como,se puder pode mandar mais links agradeço  mano.cumprimentos.alex de Moçambique

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que tem um uma colecção com as letras que quer duplicar, uma forma de escrever a sub-rotina será:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim alfabeto As New Collection

    ' Colecção que vai receber o alfabeto duplicado
    Dim alfabetoDuplicado As New Collection

   'Fora do escopo da pergunta mas preencher um array com o alfabeto para clareza
    For Index = 65 To 90
        alfabeto.Add Chr(Index)
    Next

    For t = 1 To alfabeto.Count
        alfabetoDuplicado.Add (alfabeto(t) + alfabeto(t))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: valeu ai mano deu certo o meu cordial abraçoAlex de Moçambique

Comment: mas tem um probleminha para duplicar não aceita não sei se poderia dar mais uma ajudinha eu tou fazendo isso no vb6.

Comment: como assim não aceita? que erro é que lhe aparece?

Comment: type mismatch da erro no t

Comment: type mistmatch e da erro no "t"

Comment: qual  é  a funçã o do chr?

Comment: [Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) devolve o carácter associado ao código passado. Neste caso 65 -> A...90 -> Z.
[Mais informações sobre strings em VB6](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions)

Comment: @user7752 teste novamente, havia um lapso no código (a lista a que estavam a ser adicionados os objectos tinha o nome errado. Deveria ser alfabetoDuplicado mas estava charDuplicado).

Comment: ja mas continua na mesma.

Comment: corri o código que postei em VB6 e não tive problemas. Se pudesse dar mais alguma informação sobre o error que dá, em que linha, que linguagem é que está a usar (VB6, VBA, etc), IDE.

Comment: excel vba ,no erro escreve type mismatch e da erro no t na primeira linha.

Comment: Estou sem ideias, já experimentei o código tanto em VB6 como em VBA (Excel 2013) e não encontrei problemas. Duas tentativas. Cole o código da resposta sozinho, sem mais código dentro de uma função e corra para ver se funciona. Cole o código que está a usar (edite a pergunta ou cole nos comentários) para analise.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() Dim t, alfabeto, alfabetoduplicado As New Collection For Index = 65 To 90 lstteste.AddItem Chr(Index) Next  dim alfabetoduplicado as new collection  For t = 1 To alfabeto.Count alfabetoduplicado.Add (alfabeto(t) + alfabeto(t)) Next End Sub

Comment: O problema está na seguinte linha:
Dim t, alfabeto, alfabetoduplicado As New Collection
Desta forma está a declarar que `t` vai ser uma Collection também. Não é necessário declarar `t` dado que é apenas um indice, tal como `Index` no primeiro `for`.
Mais um detalhe, não pode declarar duas collections na mesma linha, terá de ser
Dim alfabeto as new collection
Dim alfabetoDuplicado as new collection

Actualizei a resposta com a estrutura de código que pos no comentário.

Comment: o problema esta mesmo no for t = 1 to alfabeto.count   da o erro type mismatch

Comment: Pergunto novamente, que erro é que está a ter no `for t = 1 to alfabeto.Count`? Tenha em atenção que se estiver a tirar os elementos de outra colecção (que não `alfabeto`) terá de alterar o nome aqui `for t = 1 to alfabeto.Count`. E caso não seja uma colecção, pode não expor a função Count e deverá procurar a equivalente para a estrutura de dados que está a usar.

Comment: muito obrigado pela atencao,valeu nesmo .abs